# approximation of binomial coefficient by exponentiation

Tags: exponentiation, approximation, binomial-theorem

Show that inequality holds for every n, k.
$$\ { n \choose k} \leq \frac{n^k}{k!}. ( \, 1-\frac {k}{2n} ) \,^{k-1}   $$

I used Stirling's formula but I stucked, which is 
$$\ { n \choose k} = \frac{n^{n}}{(n-k)^{n-k}.k^k}. \sqrt \frac{n}{2\pi(n-k)k } $$

Then I distributed Binomial and stuck again in 
$$\ { n \choose k} = \prod_{i=1}^k \frac {n+1-i}{i} \leq \frac {n^k}{k!} $$

Comment: What is the question? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\binom nk&=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=\frac n{k!}((n-1)(n-k+1))((n-2)(n-k+2))\cdots\\
&\le\frac n{k!}\left(n-\frac k2\right)^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{n^k}{k!}\left(1-\frac k{2n}\right)^{k-1}\;.
\end{align}